# Why aren't strings allowed to be embedded into f-strings just as values?

Tags: python, f-string

```
print(f"my age is {54} and my name is {True}")
```

yields

```
my age is 54 and my name is True
```

and the following also works

```
print(f"my age is {54.0} and my name is {True}")
```

However, when I place a string inside the curly brackets:

```
print(f"my age is {54.0} and my name is {"Bill"}")
```

I get an Invalid Syntax error.

So how is the string data type different from other primitives in this instance?

Comment: Because `"` indicates the end of your string.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0536/#id8; try `'Bill'`.

Comment: So I guess I need to use an escape character.

Comment: Or use single quotes.

Comment: So it's either different quotes or escape characters, got it.

Comment: If you know the value, then why would you need to insert it?

Comment: @Sayse, mostly for no reason, just to broaden my knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not different, you just need to use a different type of quotes for the f-string itself and the string inside the placeholder:

```
print(f'my age is {54.0} and my name is {"Bill"}')
```

You can even nest f-strings using different quoting characters:

```
print(f'{f"{123}"}')
```